# How to create form/report on a table which has only primary keys?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Im trying to create a form with a report on a table that has only primary keys.

I have a table:

```
create table WRITE
(
      author varchar(5) references AUTHOR (authorcode) ,
      book varchar(20)  references BOOK (bookid),
      primary key(author,book)
);
```

I'm using APEX Application Builder to create a form on a table with report;
But When I get to the "Select the columns to include in the form" , I have no options to select from because I only have unique primary keys in my table.

Comment: It would help to know what version of APEX you're on. Things changed considerably in APEX 19.1 for new forms.

Comment: I'm on APEX 4.2.4, my instructor limited our usage to this version only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which Apex version is it? I've tried it on apex.oracle.com which uses 19.1 and it doesn't have that problem.

Anyway, two options I can think of:

- temporarily drop primary key constraint

  - then create report + form pages
  - after you're done, create the primary key constraint once again
- create an interactive report (using the wizard)

  - then create a form, manually adding items
  - this isn't as easy as it looks like because you'll have to create all processes as well (initialization one, along with automatic row processing)

I presume that the first option is a lot simpler.

Comment: Thanks for the help, both didn't work but it inspired me to add a column then making forms and removing it again. Much appreciated.